# How do I implement asynchrounous caching?

Tags: c#, asp.net

We're using the following pattern to handle caching of universal objects for our asp.net application.

```
private object SystemConfigurationCacheLock = new object();
public SystemConfiguration SystemConfiguration
{
    get
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Cache["SystemConfiguration"] == null)
            lock (SystemConfigurationCacheLock)
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current.Cache["SystemConfiguration"] == null)
                    HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("SystemConfiguration", GetSystemConfiguration(), null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, new CacheItemUpdateCallback(SystemConfigurationCacheItemUpdateCallback));
            }
        return HttpContext.Current.Cache["SystemConfiguration"] as SystemConfiguration;
    }
}

private void SystemConfigurationCacheItemUpdateCallback(string key, CacheItemUpdateReason reason, out object expensiveObject, out CacheDependency dependency, out DateTime absoluteExpiration, out TimeSpan slidingExpiration)
{
    dependency = null;
    absoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1);
    slidingExpiration = Cache.NoSlidingExpiration;
    expensiveObject = GetSystemConfiguration();
}

private SystemConfiguration GetSystemConfiguration()
{
    //Load system configuration
}
```

The problem is that when under load (~100,000 users) we see a huge jump in TTFB as the CacheItemUpdateCallback blocks all the other threads from executing until it has finished refreshing the cache from the database.

So what I figured we needed is solution that when the first thread after an expiry of the cache attempts to access it, an asynchronous thread is fired off to update the cache but still allows all other executing threads to read from the old cache until it has sucessfully updated.

Is there anything built into the .NET framework that can natively handle what I'm asking, or will I have to write it from scratch? Your thoughts please...

A couple of things...

The use of the HttpContext.Current.Cache is incidental and not necessarily essential as we've got no problem using private members on a singleton to hold the cached data.

Please don't comment on the cache times, SPROC effeciency, why we're caching in the first place etc as it's not relevent. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out after several hours of investigation that the problem is not the CacheItemUpdateCallback blocking other threads as I originally thought, in fact it did exactly what I wanted it to asynchronously but it was the garbage collector stopping everything to clean up the LOH.

Comment: Not to use this pattern to store objects that could subsequently end up on the LOH.

Answer (score 0):

AppFabric might be a good fit for what you're looking for.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee695849

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff383731.aspx